# How to edit table contents from another page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to add a page to my website that will have a table that will display the products that are available.

What I would like to be able to do, is make it so that the contents of the table can be changed from another page (say an admin page). Is it possible to do something like this using JavaScript or something similar? If so can you please point me in the right direction.

Much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please add what have you tried so far.

Comment: @OndraŽižka [***See this Meta thread***](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122987/191759).
------------
OP: You could try making a simple PHP page. The table could be filled automatically from a MySQL/MSSQL database.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I haven't actually tried anything yet, but I've googled it a bit and I haven't found anything that I really want so I posted on here to see if was actually possible and if so how to do it.

Comment: @JeffNoel I've got a basic php page for that particular page atm but as of now it hasn't got any rows in the table because I don't know how rows there needs to be seeing as the admin will be adding new content at different times.

Comment: @MatthewWebb For the row count, there's not difference either there's only 1 row, or 10,000 rows. What matters is if the admin will have the ability to add columns, when it would make the database system a bad option. Another way to do it would be in `JSON` or in `XML`. You could also just create and external `HTML` page containing ONLY the table and its content. On the admin page, this could be loaded in a `div` with the `contenteditable` property and you could make buttons to "add one row", for instance. ***EDIT:*** JSON would be prefered if you plan to have a lot of rows. (smaller size).

Comment: @JeffNoel How would I go about doing that? I assume I would create a HTML page with the table (and a certain number of rows and columns) but how would I go about allowing the admin to edit the table? I've not come across the contenteditable property before.

Also Just in case this isn't clear. I need it so that the admin can upload a new item, change the product description, upload an image of the product and also be able to change the prices (it's a special offer page so its going to have a row called "was" and also "now")

Comment: @MatthewWebb I'm working on something for you. Hold on!

Comment: @JeffNoel Will do. I really appreciate all this help, I thought it would be possible but while I have some knowledge of PHP and Java it's probably not enough for doing something like this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible solution

Using an AJAX call, you could **store the table** itself **in an HTML file.**

Here is an example page. If you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask them. I added a few functions such as *Add Row*.

## [LIVE DEMO](http://testajax.comoj.com/)

### Admin management page (index.html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery AJAX</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    tr, td,th{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border:1px solid;
    }
    td{
        height:22px;
        min-width:125px;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">"http://jquery.com"</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* ---------------------------------- */
        /* See the SCRIPT part of this answer */
        /* ---------------------------------- */
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>jQuery AJAX Table</h1>
    <section>
        <article>
            <div id="myTable" contenteditable></div>
            <nav data-type="table-tools">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="addRow">New row</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="addColumn">New column</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" id="saveTable">Save table</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

### SCRIPT

```
    /* On page load */
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var getTable = function () {
            /*We empty the div */
            $('#myTable').html('');
            /*We load the table */
            $.get('myTable.html', function (callback_data) {
                var table = callback_data;
                document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = table;
            });
        };
        getTable();

        /* ----- */

        /* New row button */
        $('#addRow').click(function (event) {
            /* Prevents the real anchor click event  (going to href link)*/
            event.preventDefault();

            /* We get the number of columns  in a row*/
            var colNumber = $($('#myTable tbody tr')[0]).children('td').length;

            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < colNumber; i++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n"));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
            $('#myTable tbody').append(tr);
        });

        $('#addColumn').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.each($('#myTable table thead tr'), function () {
                $(this).append('<th></th>');
            })
            $.each($('#myTable table tbody tr'), function () {
                $(this).append('<td></td>');
            });
        });

        $('#saveTable').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var table = $('#myTable').html();
            $.post('saveTable.php', {
                'myTable': table
            }, function (callback_data) {
                console.log(callback_data);
                $('#myTable').slideToggle('fast');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    getTable();
                    $('#myTable').slideToggle();
                }, 100);

            });
        });
    });
```

---

### saveTable.php

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['myTable']))
        die('No data provided.');

    $table = $_POST['myTable'];

    $handle = fopen('myTable.html','w');
    $result = fwrite($handle,$table);
    if($result)
        fclose($handle);
    else
        die('Error writing file');
?>
```

---

### myTable.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Lorem ipsum dolor.</th>
            <th>Velit, vero, quis.</th>
            <th>Id, dolore, commodi!</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Voluptatibus, maiores.</td>
            <td>Quod, et.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Ex, assumenda!</td>
            <td>Qui, pariatur!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Alias, amet.</td>
            <td>Delectus, itaque!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Praesentium, quod.</td>
            <td>Dolor, praesentium?</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Beatae, perferendis!</td>
            <td>Voluptates, earum!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Ratione, quis.</td>
            <td>Cupiditate, repellendus.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Porro, labore.</td>
            <td>Eligendi, nemo!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
            <td>Soluta, suscipit.</td>
            <td>Dolorem, dolores.</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The example you've present is perfect. Just a couple of questions. Is possible to add an option so that you can add an image to it? Also seeing as I don't want anyone to change the contents of the table. Can I have it so that when the table on the admin page gets updated, the table on the special offers page gets update as well?

Comment: To show the table on another page for the public, just put it in a `div` element that **does not** have the `contenteditable` attribute. There's many ways to let the user add an image to it, but it complexifies itself fast enough: max width/height of the picture, cropping/resizing it, uploading the picture from the user's PC needs way more work to be done coding-wise than taking the picture from an URL. But it's definitely possible. [**Here is an example on contenteditable attribute**](http://jsfiddle.net/MMQWP/). [**How to select a good answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/191759)

Comment: I think I may have confused myself a little bit (I understand more or less the process, I'm just confused where everything goes). So the code for the index.html (and also the script) will go in the admin page. While the myTable.html will go in the special offers page. Am I right?

Comment: myTable.html is kind of our **database**, this is where the actual table exists and is stored. We load it in both the admin page and the special offer page. For the special offer page, you would actualy only need the `getTable()` function (and don't forget to execute/call it) since users won't need the tools to add rows and stuff..

Comment: Will this work if all my files are php or does it have to be a html file? Special Offers is a php file and when I copy the "get table" function (just that bit), I'm getting an error at the end and when I try to close it off with script, i'm still getting an error.

Comment: It will work even if your files wear the `.php` extension. The error might be because you did not include jQuery into the page. Inser the following line between your `<head></head>` tags, just before the `<script>` opening tag where the `getTable()` function belongs: 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` (PS: Lunch time, I'm back at 1PM (in 55 minutes))

Comment: Hmmm, I've put both the jquery script and the getTable function in the head tags and I'm still getting a syntax error at the end even if i close it off with a </script> tag

Comment: It works fine in the admin.html page but I noticed, if (on the admin page) I put a </script> in the same place as I have on special offers, then I get the syntax error.

Comment: @MatthewWebb The `$(document).ready(function(){});` function is not closed correctly. Add `});` before the `</script>` closing tag on the special offer page.

Comment: I've closed it up and I'm getting no errors on the page, however the table isn't showing up on the special offers page unless I put in the code from the myTable.html into the special offers page, however even if I do that, the admin page only changes the content of the table in the admin page and not the one on the special offers page. Am I doing something wrong? Here's the link to the special offers page. http://www.claybrookeanimalfeeds.co.uk/special-offers.php to get to the admin page just delete the special-offers.php and put in admin.html

Comment: Also is it possible to have a remove from table function as well? Because as it stands at the moment, when the admin adds a new row it'll just keep extending the page, so I would like to be able to remove some rows

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways.

#### Not involving server-side

You need a reference to the other window. You can get that e.g. by opening the window - `window.open()`.

Then you use the HTML DOM methods, e.g. the `document.getElementById(...)` and then the specific element's API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp

#### Involving server-side

This means that one page would send some data to the server and the other would read them.

You can use the AJAX concept for that - see the answer with `XMLHttpRequest`.

The other page would have to check periodically, or the first page would have to give it some signal - call some JavaScript method you wrote, or reload the window. Other option would be to use the *push* concept, but that's currently an advanced technique.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XMLHttpRequest` for this , but I would recommend that you use jQuery which would then be the `$.ajax()` function. What this does is send data to the server without refreshing the page or without anybody knowing about it really.

So what you could do is on the admin side is send some changes data to the server and on the client side unless you use a `Web Socket` you would have to contact the server every so many seconds to see if there are any changes. then the server would send you any changes that would  have been made by the admin then you would work with that result with javascript to display changes on the web page.

> [What is Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)
>
> [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
>
> Here is the requested example using jQuery
>
> in your php you would have something like this

```
if($_POST['type'] === 'updateProduct') {
   // update database with new price
   // You could have a field in the database that now say's 
   // that the product has been updated

   //  send the response 

   echo 'done';
}

// And the admin ajax something like this 
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'linkToYourFile.php', // The php file that will process the request
    data: {
        type: 'updateProduct', // This is all the data you wan't to send to your php file
        productID: 8484737,
        newPrice: '$100.99'
    },
    success: function( result ) { // if we get a response 
      if(result === 'done') {
        // The product has been updated from the admin side 
      }
    }
});

// on the client side

if($_POST['type'] === 'checkForUpdates') {
   // Contact the database and check that $_POST['productID']
   // has been updated 
   // use php's json_encode function to echo the result
}

var checkForUpdates = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'LinkToYourFile.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            type: 'checkForUpdates',
            productId: 8484737
        },
        sucess: function ( result ) {
            if( result.updated === true ) {
               someElementPrice.textContent = result.newPrice;
            } 
        }
    });
};

window.setInterval(checkForUpdates, 3000); // Send's the update request every 3 seconds
```

> Note - it's not easy to do this stuff if your not familiar with it. but you will learn. 
>   Thats the fun part. and there is a lot more to it behind the scenes, but this is the idea of it

Comment: I'm not very knowledgeable in J Query, how would I go about doing this? Could you show me either some code or a working example please?

Comment: @MatthewWebb See this [**Official jQuery example doc**](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/).

Comment: I have added an example. it may seem complicated to you, but it was for everyone at the start.

Comment: @Connor Cheers, I'll have a read of and perhaps do a bit of testing. I am learning php atm but I'm getting the hang of it. I only discovered the benefits of using PHP a few months back

Comment: @Connor I have a couple of questions that may sound silly, but as I said i'm still learning.

I've noticed a couple of times you've mentioned database, will this work if I don't have a database?

Also in the Data: { type :'updateproduct' Is it possible to leave this blank as I don't have any idea what information that they will add in (obviously I know the titles of the content but not actually the values)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Matthew, this isn't the sort of question that i would like to answer in a comment. i would be happy to help you if you come to the http://javascriptroom.com chat room. i have upVoted this answer so you have enough reputation to enter the chat room

Comment: actually you need 20+ rep to enter chat room ....

Comment: @Connor No problem. I've got an answer which I'm working on right now from Jeff below. Thanks for the help anyway, and if his answer doesn't work (for whatever reason, it seems to exactly what I want) I know who to fall back on if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some limitations:

You should change the table that displays the products, to fetch the values beeing displayed using ajax. Then you have 2 possibilities: (I'm pretty sure there are more but I only think of those 2 at the moment)

- create a timer which will fetch the values for a product every X seconds
- create a listener that will be called when a value in the db gets updated

This way you can change the values in an backend and the will be automatically updated in your frontend view.
You can have a look at the [meteor framework](http://www.meteor.com) where they use '[Live HTML](http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtml)' excessive.