# How to generate input field in tr dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to create input field by clicking a button.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Age
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Nithin
        </td>
        <td>
            24
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn">add row</button>
```

On the click of button I want to display a textbox which will allow users to add content to a table.

How can this be done?

EDIT:-
I want to consider the above td.It must generate based on the above td count

Comment: You want to append new rows with input fields or you want to have an input field on your first row after the headings?

Comment: Please provide desired output, and some code effort as well.

Comment: You should really be much more clear with your question next time, instead of downvoting people because you weren't clear...that isn't right.

Comment: you are right..I am sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

First of all, let me explain the use of `innerHTML` instead of `.append()`:

[**Performance**](http://jsperf.com/html-innerhtml-vs-appendchild).

---

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHdDs/1/)

---

### Solution

Add the following HTML code under your button `#btn`:

### HTML

```html
<div id="addRow">
    <input type="text" id="name" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="age" value="" />
    <button id="createNewRow">Add new row</button>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#addRow {
    display:none;
}
```

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
/* We we click the #btn# */
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function () {

    /* We show the add row form (or hide it) */
    $('#addRow').slideToggle();

    /* We also change the text of the #btn 
       and empty inputs if necessary       */
    if ($(this).text() == "add row") $(this).text('hide form');
    else {
        $('#age,#name').val('');
        $(this).text('add row');
    }
});

/* Here we add a new row using .innerHTML */
$('#createNewRow').on('click', function () {
    var name = $('#name').val(),
        age = $('#age').val();

    $('table tbody')[0].innerHTML += "<tr> <td>" + name + "</td><td>" + age + "</td></tr>";
});
```

---

### Alternative

You could use the AJAX/HTML table editing way. See this thread: [**How to edit table contents from another page using javascript.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573142/1451422)
[The related demo](http://jfnoel.com/SO/dynamic_table/admin.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle which is appending new rows to your table with two new input fields on each new click on your button: `button#btn`:

Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/8e7ww/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/8e7ww/1/)

Pure jQuery source:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button#btn').click(function() {
        var new_row = $('<tr>');

        var input_name = $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Your Name',
            name: 'names[]'
        });

        var input_age = $('<input>').attr({
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Your Age',
            name: 'ages[]'
        });

        var column_name = $('<td>').append( input_name );
        var column_age = $('<td>').append( input_age );

        new_row.append( column_name ).append( column_age );

        $('table').first().find('tbody').append( new_row );
    });
});
```

Comment: Here you put age name like that..My problem is it must be changed.The fields are coming from the database so it must changed.

Comment: @Nithu Change it then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = 'yourInputName';

$('#btn').on('click', function(name) {
    $('#myTable').append('<input type="text" name="' + name + '" />');
});
```

And give an id to your table (or a class, or whatever you want, and update the selector in $('#myTable')).

Comment: It will destroy the table structure...

Comment: ^ You need to append to a `<td>`

Comment: If you need to append something, then it's a tr, not a td...

Comment: Here you just put tr td.But i want to create dynamically in the base of above tr

Comment: Why do you want to create it dynamically ? Can't you just create it statically and display it if needed ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn").on('click', function() { 
        var count = $('table').children('tbody').children('tr').children('td').length; 
        for ( var i =0; i <count; i++ ) { 
          $('table tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');    
        }
});
```

Comment: that will append the input into the button...

Comment: ^ You need to append to a `<td>`

Comment: Here you just put tr td.But i want to create dynamically in the base of above tr

Comment: @Nithu (Updated)dynamically insense when you click inputs are created based on the count.

Comment: @screenmutt "On the click of button I want to display a textbox which will allow users to add content to a table." before edit, OP haven't pointed that it should be table.

Comment: @zlomerovic previously OP haven't mentioned the spot to appended.  so to make simple I just appended to `button` :)

Comment: That was the impression I got, and regardless you appended it to a button. But you updated. So it's all cool.

Comment: Yes you are right..Here the textbox is coming in new line.So how can I append that tr last.i want to avoid it from for loop

Comment: @Nithu `$('table tr:last').append('<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>');`  This appends to the last tr in table.

Comment: But some problem is there

Comment: @Nithu Possible to share it in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/7SXLv/1/).

Use [jQuery's Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $("table").append('<tr><td colspan="2"><textarea rows="50" cols="5"></textarea></td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: HTML styling in jQuery, what else...

Comment: Those should have been `rows` and `cols`, my bad. Now they are all HTML tags. I updated code and jsFiddle.